# db.submitchanges 1 of 2 updates failed

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

This is not a new topic, but the solution that worked for me was pretty simple and I liked to share it.

I am new to Linq. I added few fields to the database in SQL; then I added them to my solution. I tried to run the project and it gave this error "1 of 2 updates failed" at the command "db.submitchanges".

Answer (score 1):

The solution was so simple. My table was out of sync; so I deleted the table I modified from the dbml file and added it again, run custom tool and run my project. Everything worked well after.

Comment: If that did not work, compare your new column in the designer file with database structure, and make sure it has the right Null settings (accept null or not). Usually, this is referred to CanBeNull=true in the designer.
Notice: every time you run custom tool the settings reset to the wrong value again.